# How do I prevent zsh from suspending python script

Tags: sleep-wake, python

Someone once told me that zsh is just a different version of bash because of some copyright thing, so I guess I ask this question here.  I have a python script that's running in a terminal and for no reason it just stops. When I interrupt it says:

zsh: suspended python myscript.py

I dont think it's my code.  I think this is a "feature". How do I prevent this feature from happening?

I read this:
http://technosophos.com/2012/06/20/terminal-oops-resume-stopped-process-osx-linux-or-unix.html

but as there is no prompt when the script is running I can't type fg

There's also this for bash:
https://superuser.com/questions/99247/stop-a-mac-from-sleeping-while-a-bash-script-is-running-then-allow-it-to-sleep/807193#807193

Is there a python version?

Answer (score 1):

Well, whoever told you that, had no clue.  `Bash` is a shell.  `Zsh` is a different shell.  `Ksh` is a third shell.  `Tcsh` is... well, you get the idea.  These all ship with macOS.

Having said that... how do you "interrupt" your script?  If you are typing ^Z, then **you** are suspending it, that's what ^Z does.  An "interrupt" is ^C.

Is this script supposed to be displaying some output?  Can you share this script?

Type ^T and see what the shell says is going on.

```
[698] mbp13 $ python3 -c "input()"
load: 3.20  cmd: Python 59024 waiting 0.02u 0.02s
load: 3.09  cmd: Python 59024 waiting 0.02u 0.02s
```

Example above... python is waiting for input.

Comment: I am not hitting ^Z.  However, I did just try python myscript.py & and it went for awhile.  Then it stopped as is usual.  I typed fg and enter and it started up again.  Does that mean every half hour or so I have to hit fg?  Also, chrome is now the foreground because I'm typing this to you.  Does that mean my zsh is in the background again?

Comment: Try without the &